# CoffeeScript onbeforeunload responding with function not string

Tags: javascript, browser, coffeescript, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to prompt the use if they have any unsaved emails before they reload the current page.  The unsaved emails are stored in a hash called unsaved.  I wrote the the scripting in CoffeeScript.

If I use this code

```
  window.onbeforeunload = () ->
    return "Your emails are not saved.  Click \"Save Email\" on any email to save them all.  If you would like to discard your emails, just leave this page"  if unsaved.count > 0
```

Rather than prompting me with the message I get:

```
function ( data, fn ) {
        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    }

Are you sure you want to reload this page?
```

The CoffeeScript is translated as:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if (unsaved.count > 0) {
    return "Your emails are not saved.  Click \"Save Email\" on any email to save them all.  If you would like to discard your emails, just leave this page";
  }
};
```

How should I go about getting CoffeeScript to return the string rather than the function?

Comment: There's something else going on, there's nothing in your CoffeeScript that would produce your `return $("form.edit_email_template").first().submit;`. Have a look at a [simplified version](http://coffeescript.org/#try:count%20%3D%2010%0Awindow.onbeforeunload%20%3D%20()%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22Pancakes%22%20if%20count%20%3E%200).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really CoffeeScript related. The property `window.onbeforeunload` expects a string or void return value from your function, but if `unsaved.count <= 0` you're returning something else:

```
return $("form.edit_email_template").first().submit;
```

Because the return value is non-void, it will attempt to cast the `submit` function into a string. To be honest I'm not sure why CoffeeScript generated that part, because it doesn't seem to appear in the original script.

That said, you should return `void` if you don't want to see the dialog:

```
if (unsaved.count > 0) {
    return 'your emails are not saved.';
} else if (window.onbeforeunload) {
    $("form.edit_email_template").first().submit();
}
```

Comment: @muistooshort My brain must have short circuited, you're absolutely right :)

Comment: +1 I nearly laughed out loud at public transportation because of this comment^^
Btw is that urahara?